# Docker isn't sending data to local host

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, containers, devops

I tried to containerize a server using Docker for practicing but it doesn't work when it's containerized.

My simple Node.js server looks likes this:

```js
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log("data is recieved from the server");
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello world');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I suspect something might be wrong with my `package.json`, it looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "dockerservers",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "first server for dockering",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start":"node app.js"
  },


  "author": "scully86",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

And my `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
# Use the official Node.js 18 image as the base image
FROM node:18
# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install


# Expose the port on which the server listens
EXPOSE 3000

ENV NAME dockerservers

# Start the server
CMD ["node","app.js"]
```

I successfully built the image and ran it with this command:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 nodeserver
```

All the things working properly until now.

The problem is, the Node.js server is not sending response to the exposed port and this error is shown:

[image: image of error]

Can anyone help? I've been stuck for almost a day now.

Comment: try changing `hostname` to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: I tried this well but the error is shown as ** This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://0.0.0.0:3000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.  **

Comment: you would still access the website at `localhost/127.0.0.1`, listening on `0.0.0.0` just means listening on all interfaces

Comment: can you send logs from the docker server so that we could understand more what happened? also the output of a command `curl -v http://localhost:3000` would be quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that changing the `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` fixes this.

Using original code -

```
iarc13@13 so1 % curl -v localhost:3000
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

After changing to 0.0.0.0, rebuilding the image and running..

```
iarc13@13 so1 % curl -v localhost:3000
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Wed, 05 Jul 2023 15:15:35 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5
< Content-Length: 11
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Hello world%
```